# Registry in win32 application on x64 machine

Tags: winapi, registry, installshield

I'm using installshield 2010 express edition to make setup file of win32 application.

I have some problem to register some registry keys.

I configured the `installshield` project(.ise) to register two registry entry like below.

1. [`HKCU\Software\ProgName\SomeKeys`]
2. [`HKLM\Software\ProgName\SomeKeys`]

When I install this setup on a x64 machine, the HK key writes to the `Wow6432Node` [`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\ProgName\SomeKeys`]. It's just what i want.

BUT HKCU does not write anything to the `Wow6432Node`. 
It write on [`HKCU\Software\ProgName\SomeKeys`] not [`HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\ProgName\SomeKeys`].

Why this problem occurred.

Please give me any advices. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working correctly, by design on Microsoft's part.  Please read the MSDN documentation:

[Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx)

> Redirected keys are mapped to physical locations under `Wow6432Node`.

[Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253.aspx)

> Under WOW64, certain registry keys are *redirected*. When a 32-bit or 64-bit application makes a registry call for a redirected key, the registry redirector intercepts the call and maps it to the key's corresponding physical registry location. For more information, see [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx).
>
> Other registry keys are *shared* by both 32-bit and 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. 32-bit registry calls to shared keys are not redirected. Instead, one physical copy of the key is mapped into each logical view of the registry.

User-defined subkeys underneath `HKCU\Software` are **shared**, so there is no `Wow6432Node` subkey for them.

User-defined keys underneath `HKLM\Software` are **redirected**, so there is a `Wow6432Node` subkey for them.

Comment: Note that some computers *do* have a `HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node` key, but only because of a bug.  It isn't a "real" 32-bit node, just an ordinary registry key written by software with a hard-coded path.

Comment: Agreed.  Some people still have a hard time understanding that they should *NEVER* access `Wow6432Node` keys directly, they should let the Registry Redirector handle that on their behalf, by specifying the appropriate 32bit/64bit view flags when opening/creating keys.

Comment: Every computer I have contains this key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Active Setup` which makes me chuckle. Even MS can't get this right!

Comment: This document has the same oops: [ACTIVE SETUP AND HOW TO IMPLEMENT IT](http://www.etlengineering.com/installer/activesetup.txt). On my machine, even Embarcadero has the same oops in one specific key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\AutoRun\UpdateCheck`.